# Change column B values for all subsequent occurences of column A values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Take this table with two colums:

| Fruit | First Occurence? |
| --- | --- |
| "Apple" | "Yes" |
| "Orange" | "Yes" |
| "Apple" | "Yes" |
| "Apple" | "Yes" |
| "Kiwi" | "Yes" |
| "Banana" | "Yes" |
| "Apple" | "Yes" |
| "Orange" | "Yes" |
| "Orange" | "Yes" |
| "Banana" | "Yes" |

Made using this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana"],
    'First Occurence?': ["Yes"]*10
})
```

How can I efficiently change values of the second column where the value in the first column has already appeared at least once? The desired result being this:

| Fruit | First Occurence? |
| --- | --- |
| "Apple" | "Yes" |
| "Orange" | "Yes" |
| "Apple" | "No" |
| "Apple" | "No" |
| "Kiwi" | "Yes" |
| "Banana" | "Yes" |
| "Apple" | "No" |
| "Orange" | "No" |
| "Orange" | "No" |
| "Banana" | "No" |

- It can't be a loop as this takes too long
- The rows must end up in the same order they started

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated) to identify the duplicate values and then using [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html?highlight=mask#pandas.DataFrame.mask), assign a NO

```
# duplicated Fruits will come up as False, and First_occurrence be made to No
df['First Occurence?']= df['First Occurence?'].mask(df.duplicated('Fruit'),'No')
```

```
    Fruit   First Occurence?
0   Apple   Yes
1   Orange  Yes
2   Apple   No
3   Apple   No
4   Kiwi    Yes
5   Banana  Yes
6   Apple   No
7   Orange  No
8   Orange  No
9   Banana  No
```

Comment: Both answers work well and are approximately as fast as the other. This answer leaves the "Yes" cells as they are (useful if multiple categories already exist in that column), and Mozway's answer allows you to choose after how many duplicates the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['First Occurence?'] = np.where(df['Fruit'].duplicated(), 'No', 'Yes')
```

More generic alternative with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) that enable to select any nth item (0-based):

```
df['First Occurence?'] = np.where(df.groupby('Fruit').cumcount().eq(0), 'Yes', 'No')
```

output:

```
    Fruit First Occurence?
0   Apple              Yes
1  Orange              Yes
2   Apple               No
3   Apple               No
4    Kiwi              Yes
5  Banana              Yes
6   Apple               No
7  Orange               No
8  Orange               No
9  Banana               No
```

Comment: Great answer to the question thanks! Although I confess my example question wasn't quite true to my actual problem: the "First Occurrence?" column equivalent actually has several categories not just "Yes".

So rather than setting all first occurrences as yes, could your solution be changed to leave the values in the second column as they are if it's the first occurrence? Sorry!